# During the recent Python Build's

Tags: python

Which Python build was up to date during 1999? I'm trying to run module files through the python interpreter, and the example in the book doesn't read the same syntax as the print command works for Python 3.5.  What syntax should I use running module files during the Python 3.5 Build.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. You probably want to use Python 2 instead of 3.5. Although, if whatever book you are using is from 1999, then you might need Python 1. I suggest you get a modern book.

Comment: Cesar, that would most likely have been python 1.5., which was released late fall 1997. You may have a hard time working with it if there are problems because the tutorials, support and stacks are heavily weighted to modern releases. But definitely, Juanpa is right, 3.5 will not be the way to go, if you do not find a newer source, install and use the oldest version of python 2 you are able to find.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia ([History of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python)), Python 1.5 or 1.6 would be your best bet; though I would probably recommend finding a more current book (or online resource) if possible, since learning an obsolete version of the language won't be very useful (you'll have to find old versions of every library you want to use) and may cause you headaches in the future when you want to learn the new syntax.